# Image keeps disappearing after refreshing the page

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

So I'm doing a web app in react and decided to do a navbar, I included an image there, but every time I refresh the page the image disappears. It disappears refreshing through the code or through the refresh button on the web. I really dont understand why but also Im really new to this part of programming.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MenuItems } from "./MenuItems";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import "./Navbar.css";
import config from "../../config";

class Navbar extends Component {
  state = { clicked: false };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked });
  };

  render() {


    const backHome = () => {
      window.location.replace(config.PORTAL_URL);
      return;
    };


    return (
      <nav className="NavBarItems">
        <img
          src="image.png"
          width="15%"
          height="auto"
          onClick={() => backHome()}
          className="image"
        />
        <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <i className={this.state.clicked ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"} />
        </div>
        <ul className={this.state.clicked ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                  {item.title}
                </a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <Button>Sign up</Button>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

and the MenuItems class its just

```
import config from '../../config'

export const MenuItems = [{
        title: "Home",
        url: config.PORTAL_URL,
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: "Services",
        url: "#",
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: "Products",
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: "Contact us",
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: "Sign up",
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
    }
]
```

The image is stored in the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find a solution. What i did was move the image to other folder other than public, in this case i decided to put it in the same folder as the class using it. And then i did the following:

```
import logo from "./image.png"
```

and then in the place where there was the url I put "logo"

```
return (
  <nav className="NavBarItems">
    <img
      src={logo}
      width="15%"
      height="auto"
      onClick={() => backHome()}
      className="image"
    />
    <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <i className={this.state.clicked ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"} />
    </div>
    <ul className={this.state.clicked ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
      {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
              {item.title}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
    <Button>Sign up</Button>
  </nav>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after adding the react-router-dom library to a project.

Adding a slash to the src tag helped:

```
src="/logo.png"
```

The logo and title are wrapped in a NavLink component:

```
<NavLink
    className="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center me-10"
    reloadDocument
    to="/">
        <span className="f-w-5 d-block me-2">
        <img
            alt="logo"
            className="w-100 align-text-top"
            src="/logo.png"
        />
    </span>
    <span>{t("title")}</span>
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to developer console and click on the img source to open in new tab, See if the image opens in a new tab.

Comment: what do you mean with developer console?

Comment: I mean do inspect element.

Comment: it opens, but when i refresh the page and try to open again it gives an error